# Question about Call warrant

Tags: warrants, call-options

I have a question about whether I understand this correctly. Take the following warrant:

Call 19.03.21 Tesla 540

Currently traded for 11.27€ (13.67USD).
Am I correct to assume that once this call expires, (March 19th, 2021) I will get the difference between the closing price and $540? (assuming the share price is above 540$)
I am just wondering because the price of 11€ seems very low to me as I don't expect Tesla to lose one third of it's value in a month.
Here is the KID:
https://derinet.vontobel.ch/api/kid?isin=DE000VP7B9N4&language=en

Answer (score 1):

If TSLA is at 800 at the last trading day, you would get 800 - 540 = 260, multiplied by 0.05 (ratio according to the PDF you linked), which is 13.00 $.
Just a bit less than what you paid, not considering the fees, and you bear the risk of TSLA ending a lot lower.

Comment: Okay this makes way more sense now. I was not aware of this ratio. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me say upfront that I understand U.S. warrants and since this is a complex foreign warrant, my take may be way off.

The whole thing seems sketchy to me.  They offer 4 scenarios where you make or lose money but they offer no share price value for any of those scenarios.  They call them `Stress scenario, Unfavourable Scenario, Moderate scenario, and Favourable scenario.`  There's no way to determine where their return numbers came from or see the true payoff.

What also seems off to me is that under **What is the product?**, in scenario 1. it says:

> 1. If the Reference Price exceeds the Strike on the Valuation Date, you will receive a redemption amount on the Redemption Date which equals the amount by which the Reference Price exceeds the Strike, multiplied by the Ratio.

In the product specs below it says that the ratio is 0.05 which I think means that they're paying you 5 cents on the dollar.

If I'm right about this, "Run Forrest, run!"